# Data-annotation based validation does not work for navigation properties

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I have following classes in my program:

```
class Container
{
    public Container()
    {
        Contain = new Contain();
    }  

    public Contain Contain { get; set; }
}
class Contain
{
    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

As you see I decorated the `Code` property with `[Required]` data annotation attribute. I wrote a `Validate` method to validate my objects, too:

```
class Program
{
    static bool Validate(object command)
    {
        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(command, null, null);
        var validationMessages = new Collection<ValidationResult>();
        var result =  Validator.TryValidateObject(command, validationContext, validationMessages, true);
        Console.WriteLine("********** " + command.GetType().Name +" **************");

        foreach (var validationMessage in validationMessages)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(validationMessage);
        }
        return result;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var contain = new Contain();
        Console.WriteLine(Validate(contain));

        var container = new Container();
        Console.WriteLine(Validate(container));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

When I run the program the `Validate` method returns `true` for `container` object and returns `false` for `contain`:
[image]

But the `Container` contains an invalid `contain` object(because its `Code` property set to `null`), and so I want the `Validate` method don't validate it.

Is the any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TryValidateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772.aspx) method doesn't work recursively. Documentation says:

*This method evaluates each ValidationAttribute instance that is attached to the object type. It also checks whether each property that is marked with RequiredAttribute is provided. It **does not** recursively validate the property values of the object.*

The workaround is to write your own recursive version of TryValidateObject method. Another solution is a custom validation attribute. For details see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663501/dataannotations-recursively-validating-an-entire-object-graph).