# How to validate model in .Net Core 3.1 in console app when the model contains another class's object as a property using DataAnnotations?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, .net-core, data-annotations

I have the following request model :

```
public class VisitRequest
    {
        public ProviderInfo Provider { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(64)]
        public string PayerId { get; set; }
    }
```

And i have the custom class as follows :

```
 public class ProviderInfo
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(15)]
        public string TaxId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Qualifier is required.")]
        [MaxLength(15)]
        public string NPI { get; set; }
    }
```

I am currently using ValidationContext to do the model validations :

```
var visitData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VisitRequest>(jsonString);
var vc = new ValidationContext(visitData);
var errorResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(visitData, vc, errorResults, true);
```

My demo json request is as follows :

```
{
'Member': {
  'Qualifier': 'MedicaidID',
  'Identifier': '100'
  },                
  'ExternalVisitID': '123456789',
}
```

Now I am receiving the ErrorMessage in ErrorResult as :

```
PayerId is required.
```

But I am not getting the validations of the custom class. How to implement this in **.Net Core Console application**?
I am quite new to .Net Core so any help would be appreciated.Thanks!

---

**UPDATE :**

I followed the answer given by @John H but still there is one issue .

If my request is :

```
'Provider' : {
      'TaxId' : null
}
```

it will work fine , because it is able to identify that this is the type ProviderInfo object.

But if my request does not contain any info regarding the Provider  :

```
{
'ExternalVisitID': '123456789',
'EVVMSID': '100', 
}
```

then it is not able to validate the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In brief, this doesn't work because `TryValidateObject` doesn't support the validation of complex nested types. This was also an issue for the .NET Framework version of this type, and @reustmd created a [NuGet Package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8090614/729541) to solve the problem. Unfortunately, it doesn't support .NET Core, but I found there is a [package forked from this](https://github.com/ovation22/DataAnnotationsValidatorRecursive) which does. From the readme:

> ### Installation
>
> Available as NuGet-Package `dataannotationsvalidator`:
>
> Install-Package dataannotationsvalidator
>
> ### Usage
>
> See file `DataAnnotationsValidator/DataAnnotationsValidator.Tests/DataAnnotationsValidatorTests.cs`
>
> Short example:
>
> var validator = new DataAnnotationsValidator.DataAnnotationsValidator();
>
> var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
>
> validator.TryValidateObjectRecursive(modelToValidate, validationResults);

This should solve your problem.

As an aside, I also found [this proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31400) discussing adding this functionality to .NET. If you're interested in a technical design discussion of that proposal, there is a video posted by the .NET Foundation [discussing](https://youtu.be/t-X09mGPvNM?t=4985) it.

#### Update

For your scenario above, I've installed the above package, changed the `VisitRequest` class to make the provider required

```
public class VisitRequest
{
    [Required]
    public ProviderInfo Provider { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string PayerId { get; set; }
}
```

and then ran the following:

```
var jsonString = @"{
    ""ExternalVisitID"": ""123456789"",
    ""EVVMSID"": ""100""
}";

var modelToValidate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VisitRequest>(jsonString);

var validator = new DataAnnotationsValidator.DataAnnotationsValidator();

var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

validator.TryValidateObjectRecursive(modelToValidate, validationResults);

foreach (var item in validationResults)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ErrorMessage);

    foreach (var memberName in item.MemberNames)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{memberName}");
    }
}
```

which produces output of:

```
The Provider field is required.
    Provider
The PayerId field is required.
    PayerId
```

If you're wanting to list each field of a provider that's missing individually, even though that part of the JSON is empty, I think you'll have to fork the NuGet package and make those changes. But this is probably a reason why .NET hasn't supported this functionality out of the box, because people have different expectations for how it should behave.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I was trying to resolve this issue since 2 days. 

Comment: @VivekSheth No problem. :)

Comment: I am using this package but I am facing an issue can u please look into the UPDATE that I have added in the question.

Comment: @VivekSheth If you're wanting the `Provider` property to be required, then you should mark it with `[Required] public ProviderInfo Provider { get; set; }`. That will tell you that it's missing completely. As you have it right now, the `ProviderInfo` properties are only required _if_ you include `provider` in your JSON.

Comment: I have already marked it [Required] but it still doesn't validate it if the JSON request does not contain the property.